# How to convert a string from koi8-r to windows-1251 in c#?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cyrillic encoding in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013659/cyrillic-encoding-in-c-sharp)

What I have

```
string str = "уРБУЙВП ЧБН ЪБ ЧБЫХ РПНПЭШ"; //cyrillic
//I check this on 
site == http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en

str == koi8-r
if ( I decoder from the site)
  readeble text == windows-1251;
```

How I can convert koi8 to windows-1251 ?

Comment: Not UTF-8 I looking for koi8-r
and 
ãåðìàíèè dosn't look like РПНПЭШ

Comment: By the time it got turned into a string it is too late.  You need to convert the original *bytes* with Encoding.GetEncoding(20866).GetString() to get "Спасибо вам за вашу помощь".  You got "уРБУЙВП ЧБН ЪБ ЧБЫХ РПНПЭШ" from using 1251.

Comment: You really should look at the question linked by Ahmad, and replace UTF-8 with Windows-1251. The point is that you have to read the data as bytes, convert to a string using `Encoding.GetString`, and then convert to Windows-1251 on output using `Encoding.GetBytes`. Also, you should go back and accept the best answers to your other questions, if they helped you with your problem.