# Paradox DB: cyrillic words in a query, C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, encoding, paradox

I need to execute a query to Paradox database.
There is a table, that contains data with cyrillic words and I'm trying to use cyrillic parameters in a query like this:

```
select * 
from AccessZone zn
where zn.Name= 'Территория'
```

In AccessZone table i have records with name 'Территория' but this query returns 0 rows.

I'm encoding this query to windows-1252 encoding, but have the same result.

When I get a query result that contains cyrillic values, i have broken symbols like '??????', so, i'm decoding them from windows-1252 and then get correct values. This trick i decided to use while i was executing a query with cyrillic symbols but it didn't affect on result, i'm still has 0 rows.

I'm encoding using c# like this:

```
private static string DecodeTo1252(string source)
{
    Encoding srcEncodingFormat = Encoding.Unicode;
    Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
    try
    {
        byte[] output = Encoding.Convert(srcEncodingFormat, 
                                         dstEncodingFormat, 
                                         srcEncodingFormat.GetBytes(source));

        return dstEncodingFormat.GetString(output);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

So,how must i build a query, or encode it for querying to paradox DB?

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Cyrillic encoding in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013659/cyrillic-encoding-in-c-sharp?rq=1)?

Comment: No, it didn't help, but thanks. Actually, i know target encoding, but it doesn't change anything. I still get 0 rows after executing decoded query.

Answer (score 0):

Paradox had multiple versions in DOS and Windows products. But most or all of those used ascii coding with "code pages" in that system. You may be getting the right records. But I'm not sure how you can display that in Unicode. I think the Unicode is having a problem displaying the data obtained.  I think you will have to learn what code page was used when the data was originally stored. Paradox might have called this the Sort Order, which in at least some versions was defined by a Paradox.sor table.