# String to Ansicode Representation

Tags: c#, .net

I need to save cyrillic chars in a varchar field in MSSQL.
To do so I need to convert my string to the ansi representation of the bytes.

For Example if I change the encoding in Notepad++ from Cyrillic to ANSI the string changes from `русский язык` to `ðóññêèé ÿçûê`.
I couldn't find a way to do this in c#, is `encoding.getbytes` the right way?

Comment: Can't you use nvarchar?

Comment: no, damn legacy applications :(

Comment: Would you consider storing the data as UTF-8 in base64?

Comment: I only have control over the application writing the data, so it has to be stored exactly as described above

Comment: @Telvan That will _not_ work. Going from UTF-16 (.NET in-memory string) to ANSI has the possiblity of truncating characters so there's no way to reliably go back. You have to update both writing and reading the data, every place where it happens if you cook up your own encoding.

Comment: A better solution would be to update the database to use `nvarchar` for the column type and problem is solved. You still need to update all applications using the database to be aware of the new data type.

Comment: The basic way to do this would be to use the cyrillic encoding to go to bytes, then use the ansi encoding or whatever to go back to a string. You probably have to experiment with that scheme a bit until you replicate what Notepad++ does. Also, there will be losses in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014137/1299394).

If you are sure that the string in that column is *always* cryillic, then you can convert the string to a byte array using one encoding, then convert the byte array back to a string using a different encoding. I tried the following, and it seems to work:

```
var s = "ðóññêèé ÿçûê";
var b = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(s);
var fixedString = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(b);
Console.WriteLine(fixedString); // русский язык
```