# Encoding for richTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, richtextbox

I have 3rd party library that returns me some string - "(c) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation), 2015 Ј. ‚бҐ Їа ў  § йЁйҐ­л.". I search in google how to detect the encoding of this text and got that it's cp866 and displayed as KOI-7.

I try to encode it to windows-1251 and display the string in richTextBox. But I got  next text - "(c) ?R фR я¦рЇ ?яcт RЎR¤ў (Microsoft Corporation), 2015 ?. 'Ў? ф ячя я©р©?-«."

The output text should be - (c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2015 г. Все права защищены.

It's Russian language(cyrilic)

```
        var fromEncodind = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);//from cp866
        var bytes = fromEncodind.GetBytes(output);
        var toEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);//to windows-1251
        output = toEncoding.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12014137/4649822) you can verify the `codepage`s you need and test the string afterwards.

Find the encoding pages you need:

```
const string source = "(c) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation), 2015 Ј. ‚бҐ Їа ў § йЁйҐ­л.";
const string destination = "(c) Корпор ция М йкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2015 г. Все пр в з щищены.";

foreach (var sourceEncoding in Encoding.GetEncodings())
{

    var bytes = sourceEncoding.GetEncoding().GetBytes(source);
    foreach (var targetEncoding in Encoding.GetEncodings())
    {
        if (targetEncoding.GetEncoding().GetString(bytes) == destination)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Source Encoding: {0} TargetEncoding: {1}",sourceEncoding.CodePage,targetEncoding.CodePage);
        }
    }
}

// Result: Source Encoding: 1251 TargetEncoding: 866
```

Which confirms you were using the correct code pages.

Then to get the string you need:

```
var decodedCyrillic = Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(source));
```

You were close, but there was an extra space within the source string you provided. That caused problems with the encoding. The source string in the code above is the string encoding will recognise.

Comment: It also seems as if your output text wasn't exact. I used [Universal Cyrillic decoder](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) in order to decode the source string.