# ASP.NET _Layot.cshtml showing weird cyrillic characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, utf-8, cyrillic

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 5 app. Added utf-8 support in _Layout.cshtml but this not solving my problem. Only in shared _Layout.cshtml i get weird characters for static cyrillic text. I use devextreme components like grid, chart etc. but there is no problem the cyrillic letters are okay.
This is an example what i get:
[image]

Added lang="en" in head but not help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013659/cyrillic-encoding-in-c-sharp/12014137

Comment: Flagrant  [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example for the line with  _"profile icon"_ in Python): `'РџСЂРѕС„РёР»'.encode( 'cp1251').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'Профил'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours researching i found this:
  `<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8"/>` in `<system.web>` in `Web.config`.

This line solved my problem.